# RPM spec variable for (sub)package name?

Tags: centos, redhat, rpm, rpmbuild

RPM spec files have many special variables available within them. Do any of these variables expose the name of the current package being processed?

For single-package RPMs, the answer would be obvious, but a single spec can also produce multiple RPMs. Is there a variable, such as $RPM_PACKAGE_NAME, that rpmbuild automatically updates to align with the current %files or %pre or %post section?

Comment: not as far as I know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything obvious in the RPM source code.  There does not seem to be a possibility to access the current list of defined subpackages using RPM macros, or the package header under construction, neither using RPM macros or Lua.

What we use instead is to generate the entire package stanza in Lua, using the [built-in Lua interpreter](http://rpm.org/user_doc/lua.html).  An example is in [`glibc.spec`](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/glibc/blob/master/f/glibc.spec); search for “Array of languages” and `%package langpack-]]..lang..[[`.  Note that the syntax highlighting in the Pagure viewer is a bit off, it is confused by this cross-language nesting.

Comment: This seems like the cleanest way. I had no idea RPM had an embedded Lua interpreter. Could you please include a link to the best documentation you have on the subject? I found this: http://rpm.org/user_doc/lua.html

Comment: Thanks, I added a link. It is still surprising to see new RPM documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with the name. There is a macro for package name `%name`, but that contains only the name of the main package. However, if you really need to do this, and you are willing to do dirty hacks, you can do:

```
%package base
Summary: Filesystem for %{name}
Group: foo

%post base
echo %group
```

which will print `foo`. Similarly for `%summary`, but `%group` is safest because group is not used for anything useful.

Ehmm, did I mentioned that this is dirty dirty hack? What Florian suggested is definitely a more cleaner way.

Comment: For a main package and subpackages foo and bar, %(summary) or %group always holds the latest summary defined, whether you're installing one of the subpackages or the main package -- so useless to distinguish between them.